# Prolog list arithmetic average

Tags: prolog

I have to write a program with the following content:

"Using the built-in Prolog predicates, define a predicate
operation (L1, L2)
met when list L2 is derived from list L1 by adding as the last element of the arithmetic mean
the largest and smallest element in the L1 list. We assume that L is a numeric list and has at least one
element (you do not need to check it)."

for now i have:

```
%ex 3
%=============================================================

operation(L1,L2):-
    msort(L1,X), 
    [H|T]=X, 
    last(X,Z), 
    Y is ((H+Z)/2),
        append(L1, [Y], L2) 


%=============================================================
```

Now I have to do:

"Check the operation of the program for 2 sets of arguments. Put the results in the program as a comment"

my last code looked like this:
`operation([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2])`

Does anyone know what it should look like?

Comment: Your code seems to work, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: I do not know how to do " examples of using the predicate operation: this is to be a prologue session attached as a comment. " my last examples were bad.

Comment: Launch Prolog, load your code, run queries with your predicate, copy from the terminal, paste into your code file inside a comment.

Comment: This really is not a question about programming, since your program actually is complete and works, but about how to turn in your assignment. You should address such inquiries to your professor, not to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this actually has to do with turning in a working assignment and not the programming involved at all

Comment: when I enter queries console say only "True"... I do not know if this is what the professor is talking about

Comment: They also output the variables that are bound, which is part of the output, but this is really an issue between you and your professor. Go ask your professor for help!

Comment: okey okey i got this solution is ```% operation([1, 2, 3], L1), % L1 = [1, 2, 3, 2] 
% operation([4], L2). % L2 = [4, 4] .```